# Formatting of search results prevents MathJax rendering

Tags: bug, feature-request

When using the built-in Stack Exchange search, it used to be that sometimes the MathJax would render and sometimes it wouldn't. When it didn't, one could use the [render MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/should-chat-have-tex-support/3297#3297) bookmark to do the job.

However, I just ran a search and the displayed body was formatted as if the MathJax were finalized text. That is, there was HTML markup *inside* the MathJax code, preventing the MathJax from ever rendering in the Search results. For example:

`\sum_{k=1}^n`

is formatted in the search result as

`\sum_{<span class="result-highlight">k</span>=<span class="result-highlight">1</span>}^n`

Perhaps this is intended as a feature to allow the search terms to be highlighted, but this makes it very hard to read any of the MathJax if a search term appears in it (which is often the case). Perhaps a checkbox could be added so that we can turn off the highlighting of search terms and return the straight text of the message (with MathJax rendered, if possible).

Comment: I believe this is why it was recommended (somewhere on meta, when the new search was out) to use `"$\sum_{k=1}^n$"`

Comment: It reduces the usability of the search engine if we need to enter entire MathJax expressions into the search when we cannot be sure of what the exact MathJax expression is (spacing changes, etc.). If this is the case, I will be using more Google search.

Comment: I agree. There's also the terrible problem when one is looking for $\Bbb Q$ it may appear as `\mathbb{Q}` or `\mathbb Q` or `\Bbb{Q}` or `{\Bbb Q}` or `\Bbb Q` or `{\mathbb{Q}}` and so on.